# A babel selectlanguage issue

Tags: latex, babeljs

I want to have a multi-language document and I guess it is something wrong with \selectlanguage{magyar}. If I use the code fragment below,
(i.e. the last language is magyar) that the first \selectlanguage{magyar} works OK (presumably nothing is to be done), \selectlanguage{english} works also OK, but the second \selectlanguage{magyar} leads to message "Patching 'babel' failed." Is it a known issue?

```
 \usepackage[english,german,romanian,magyar]{babel}
    \selectlanguage{magyar}
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \selectlanguage{magyar}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [mre] instead of a code fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found to be more convenient for me to use `otherlanguage*` for multiple languages. I tried it with your combination of languages and it seems for me to work fine. I used `babel` package and `utf8`.

```
\begin{document}
ENG: In mathematics, a manifold is a topological space that locally resembles Euclidean space near each point.\\
\newline
\begin{otherlanguage*}{german}
GRMN: Mit der Version 3.1 wurde dann der Unicodeblock Mathematische alphanumerische Symbole eingeführt, der die noch fehlenden lateinischen Großbuchstaben, sämtliche lateinische Kleinbuchstaben und alle Ziffern mit Doppelstrich enthält.\\
\newline
\end{otherlanguage*}
\begin{otherlanguage*}{romanian}
RMN: Orice funcțe diferențiabilă reală H pe o mulțime simplectică poate servi ca funcție energetică sau Hamiltonian. Asociat oricărui hamiltonian avem un câmp vectorial Hamiltonian; integralele curbilinii ale câmpului vectorial Hamiltonian sunt soluții ale ecuației Hamilton–Jacobi.\\
\end{otherlanguage*}
\newline
\begin{otherlanguage*}{magyar}
MGR: A Lie-algebrák algebrai struktúrák, melyek főleg geometriai objektumok, mint például differenciálható sokaságok és Lie-csoportok vizsgálatánál hasznosak.
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```